# Check if all relevant sub-arrays match criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

There is a thatre establishment that has a number of theatre groups. Each groups is either international or not. For some reason it is necessary that each international group has at least one female actor , aka. actress. If there exists even one international group without any female actor, function `checkGenderEquality` must return false.

```
Theatre: [
    {
      groupNmae: 'Medea',
      id: 1001,
      international: false,
      actors: [
        {
          firstName: 'Vilfrid',
          birthDate: '1981-01-01',
          gender: 'Male',
        },
        {
          firstName: 'Nils',
          birthDate: '1973-10-11',
          gender: 'Male'
        },
        {
          firstName: 'Valentina',
          birthDate: '2001-05-09',
          gender: 'Female'
        }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      groupNmae: 'Hamlet',
      id: 2001,
      international: true,
      actors: [
        {
          firstName: 'Robin',
          birthDate: '1999-07-20',
          gender: 'Male'
        },
        {
          firstName: 'Johannes',
          birthDate: '1998-12-13',
          gender: 'Male'
        },
        {
          firstName: 'Ludwig',
          birthDate: '1965-03-22',
          gender: 'Male'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      groupNmae: 'King Lear',
      id: 3001,
      international: true,
      actors: [
        {
          firstName: 'Kristina',
          birthDate: '1977-04-19',
          gender: 'Female'
        },
        {
          firstName: 'Pernilla',
          birthDate: '1974-02-03',
          gender: 'Female'
        },
        {
          firstName: 'Bruno',
          birthDate: '1970-02-23',
          gender: 'Male'

        }
      ]
    },
    {
      groupNmae: 'Medea',
      id: 4001,
      international: false,
      actors: [
        {
          firstName: 'Alfons',
          birthDate: '1986-11-01',
          gender: 'Male',
        },
        {
          firstName: 'Ulrik',
          birthDate: '1979-11-01',
          gender: 'Male'
        },
        {
          firstName: 'Oskar',
          birthDate: '2000-10-10',
          gender: 'Male'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]



 public checkGenderEquality(theatreGroup: any[]) {
    let equality = theatreGroup.every(({ t }) =>
    (
      (t.international != false) || (t.some((a) => a.gender == 'Female')))
    );
    return equality;
  }
```

Currently `checkGenderEquality` returns always `true`. How can I modify to get the correct result (which in this case is `false`; becuse Hamlet is an international group but has no female actor)?

Comment: some object have ```staff``` but no ```actors```, do the staff count as actor?

Comment: That was mistake. Now it is edited.

Comment: I updated my answer. I thought all groups are international in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer. replace filter with every and some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `group.international === false`, you don't need to check the actors. if the  `group.international === true`, you need to check actors.

**Updated:** replace filter with `every` and `some`

```js
const theatre = [
  {
    groupNmae: "Medea",
    id: 1001,
    international: true,
    actors: [
      {
        firstName: "Valentina",
        birthDate: "2001-05-09",
        gender: "Female",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    groupNmae: "Hamlet",
    id: 2001,
    international: true,
    actors: [
      {
        firstName: "Ludwig",
        birthDate: "1965-03-22",
        gender: "Male",
      },
    ],
  },
];

const isEquality = theatre.every(
  item =>
    (item.international === true &&
      item.actors.some(actor => actor.gender === "Female")) ||
    item.international === false
);

console.log(isEquality);
```